# postgresql set default value in trigger

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger, plpython

i  have a "before update trigger" on a table. How to set default value on a column ? :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$

TD["new"]["test"] = DEFAULT # Doesn't work

$$ LANGUAGE plpython2u VOLATILE;
```

Comment: What do you mean, doesn't work? Does nothing? Throws an error? If so, what error?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython-trigger.html):

> ... you can return None or "OK" from the Python function to indicate
>   the row is unmodified, "SKIP" to abort the event, or [...] "MODIFY" to indicate you've modified the new row.

Comment: ... but that is not the default value.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: You say "**the** default value", but I read the question as "How to set **a** default value" (and took `DEFAULT` to be some pseudocode placeholder, figuring that it "doesn't work" because there's no return statement). On closer inspection, it doesn't actually say either. I feel like we need some clarification...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a way to do that, as default values are evaluated *before* the triggers are called.

For simple default values (constants), you may be able to work around that by looking up `pg_get_expr(adbin, adrelid) AS default_value` in the corresponding entry in `pg_catalog.pg_attrdef` and using that, but it sure ain't a pretty solution.